# Python open("x", "r") function, how do I know or control which encoding the file is supposed to have?

Tags: python, encoding, text-files

If a python script uses the `open("filename", "r")` function to open, and subsequently read, the contents of a text file, how can I tell which encoding this file is supposed to have?

Note that since I'm executing this script from my own program, if there is any way to control this through environment variables, then that is good enough for me.

This is Python 2.7 by the way.

The code in question comes from Mercurial, it can be given a list of files to, say, add to the repository, through a file on disk, instead of passing them on the command line.

So basically, instead of this:

```
hg add A B C
```

I can write out A, B and C to a file, with newlines between each, and then execute the following:

```
hg add listfile:input.txt
```

The code that ends up reading this file is this:

```
files = open(name, 'r').read().split(delimiter)
```

Hence my question. The answer I was given on IRC when I asked which encoding I should use was this:

> it is the same encoding than the one you use on command line when passing a file argument

I take this to mean that it is the same encoding I "use" when I execute Mercurial (hg). Since I have no idea which encoding that is, I just give everything to the .NET Process object, I ask here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. Reading a file is independent of its encoding; you'll need to know the encoding in advance in order to properly interpret the bytes you read in.

For example, if you know the file is encoded in UTF-8:

```
with open('filename', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read().decode('utf-8-sig')    # -sig deals with BOM, if present
```

Or if you know the file is ASCII only:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()    # results in a str object
```

If you really don't know the encoding of the file, then there's obviously no guarantee that you can read it properly; however, you can guess at the encoding using a tool like [`chardet`](http://chardet.feedparser.org/).

**UPDATE**:

I think I understand your question now. I thought you had a file you needed to write code for, but it seems you have code you need to write a file for ;-)

The code in question probably only deals properly with plain ASCII (it's possible the  strings are converted later, but unlikely I think). So you'll want to make a text file that contains only ASCII (codepoint < 128) characters, and make sure it is saved in an ASCII encoding (i.e. not UTF-16 or anything like that). This is a little unfortunate considering that Mercurial deals with filenames, which can contain Unicode characters.

Comment: So basically the encoding is ASCII, is that what you're saying? The code in question looks like this: `files = open(name, 'r').read().split(delimiter)`

Comment: @Lasse: Not quite. I'm saying that you should only do that when the you know the encoding is ASCII (otherwise you end up with a series of bytes in your string, not characters). Have a look at the [Python docs on Unicode](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) for more info

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your comment there. The code in question cannot be changed by me. In other words, I have to conform to whatever encoding (or lack thereof) that code expects, for good or for worse. It looks from your answer as the encoding is just ASCII. If that's it, then that's it.

Comment: @Lasse: This is somewhat unrelated to your immediate problem, but would be worth a read. Your previous comment doesn't make a lot of sense. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: As it turns out, Mercurial doesn't seem to handle unicode characters in filenames at all. Even when I ask Mercurial itself to discover a file with a legal character that you wouldn't normally see in a source code filename, it crashes when it can't find the file. Apparently it interpreted the character as something else and then can't locate the file.

Comment: Read my updated question, it contains some more information. Basically, I have to write a textfile, which Mercurial will subsequently read, and parse, and understand as a "list of filenames" for various commands. Apparently Mercurial isn't fond of unicode characters in any way, form, shape, or method of entry.

Comment: @Lasse: Aha, I think I understand now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It turns out that if I used Windows-1252, the filenames that are representable in that code page is correctly read into Mercurial, at least as far as I can see, so I'll stick with that for now.